# Transfer VoiceRecorder files to Windows 11 PC from iPhone6

Tags: windows, iphone

I have this app called VoiceRecorder on my iPhone6 (icon is an old school cassette recorder) which offers options like upload to cloud and share.
Unfortunately I cannot update my Google Drive so the only option seems to be upload to Dropbox that they provide.
When I connect to my PC via USB cable, I can only get into DCIM.
How can I connect to PC and transfer these audio files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPhones don't make any files that may be on them available in the same way Android phones or other mobile devices might. I don't know if jailbreaking an iPhone allows additional file access, but I do believe iPhone's maintain their internal app storage as a database, rather than a file system, and so I'd guess that not even jailbreaking would allow normal file access to an app's data.

All that to say: your options are only those given by the app. If those methods do not work, you need to diagnose and resolve that issue rather than looking for a workaround that does not exist.